# How to troubleshoot "failed to load session" errors?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, lightdm, xmonad

On the upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04, my XMonad + Unity configuration no longer works. When I attempt to log into this session, I get "failed to load session 'xmonad'". Where can I look to figure out what's going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was to remove the references to `unity-2d-launcher` entirely from my `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/xmonad.session` (which I had configured for 11.10 the way [Mark Hansen suggested](http://markhansen.co.nz/xmonad-ubuntu-oneiric/)):

```
[GNOME Session]
Name=Xmonad Unity
RequiredComponents=gnome-settings-daemon;
RequiredProviders=windowmanager;panel;
DefaultProvider-windowmanager=xmonad
DefaultProvider-panel=unity-2d-panel
```

I always use the [shellPrompt](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Prompt-Shell.html) instead of the unity launcher anyway, so I don't miss the launcher at all.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get the XMonad + Unity configuration to work. I examined the relevant configuration files in /usr/share/xsessions/ and /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ (for more info see http://markhansen.co.nz/xmonad-ubuntu-oneiric/), and tried to run the various executables they reference. I thus discovered "gnome-panel" had been uninstalled on the upgrade, so I reinstalled it.

Comment: I installed gnome-panel and I still get failed to load session error

Answer (score 1):

The best place to look would be in `~/.xsession-errors` you could also try `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: Didn't see anything in those files. Did find some references to xmonad in the /var/log/lightdm directory, but nothing to do with the reported error message as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Unity-2d-launcher` no longer exists in `Precise`.
You can change it to `unity-2d-shell` in `gnome-session/sessions/xmonad.session`
and in `~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs`

However, even after doing this, I'm seeing a lot of weird behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly relevant: I recently upgraded and found I needed to delete the file `~/.xmonad/xmonad-x86_64-linux`, and all was fine. I run gnome + xmonad, but this step is relevant to any upgrade. See [here](http://www.mikeyboldt.com/2012/06/04/upgrade-to-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) for more notes on my experience.